# Piece-Drop Mate

Tags: chess

Find a way to checkmate Black by placing pieces!

You must use as little material as you can(in points).
You ***cannot*** place more pieces than allowed in a regular game of chess!

### The Position

[image: Good luck!]

Good luck! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can do it with

> 6 points

As follows

> 2 knights.  One knight must be at either c5 or g5, guarding the bishop and the e6 square.   The other knight must check[mate] the king.  So at d7 works.

Comment: You can prove optimality by showing a single rook clearly cannot check the king AND protect the bishop, 3 and below points trivially does not work, and 4 points does not provide enough material :)

Comment: By the way the knight could go anywhere legal, not just d7.

Comment: @MakeHellTal (I like the name!) yes, I meant that d7 worked, but so do 7 other spots.

Comment: Thanks! Glad to see someone understanding my username. ;)