# Piece-drop Mate #2

Tags: chess

[Piece-Drop Mate](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86591/piece-drop-mate) #1

Here's a second piece-drop mate, but with a twist.

Just like last time, you may **only place the maximum number of pieces allowed on the board in a regular game of chess.** You're trying to use the minimum amount of material needed(in points).

But this time, you must place pieces so that the position will lead to a mate next move, ***not an immediate mate.***
Also, there are **NO PROMOTIONS** allowed.
Good luck! ;)

[image]

Comment: Note that the position of the white pawns is illegal.

Comment: True, but that's not important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Opening bid: 6 points. Bishop on b7, knight on d7. Black is forced to play Ka7, then White can play b6#.

Real answer (thanks @Sid!)

> Bishop on b7, pawn on c7. Black is forced to play Ka7, then White can play b6#.

Comment: Bishop on b7 and pawn on c7 should also do the trick, no?

Comment: @Sid You should have answered that yourself! Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably bending the rules, but....

> 1 point or 2 points (see below)

As follows:

> put a white pawn on d7.   Put a black pawn on a6.  I'll assume this point doesn't count against white, but even if it does, it makes the solution 2 points.   Then, bxa6+ followed by Qb7#

Comment: doesn't work; has to be a 1 move mate.

Comment: @MakeHellTal Well, it says mate on next move, but doesn't specify if it's currently white or black's move.  If it's whites move then it would be mate on next move!

Comment: Correct, I overlooked that

Answer (score 0):

I can do it in 3 points:

> Place pawns on b7, a7, and a6.

Comment: @I N T E R E S T I N G Kxa7 and how do you plan to mate Black in 1?

Comment: Plus, that places 10 pawns on board, exceeding the limit of 8.

Comment: @MakeHellTal - Ohhh.... I completely forgot about that. Oops!

Comment: @MakeHellTal - I misunderstood the direction... Oops!