# Piece-drop Mate #3

Tags: chess

[Piece-Drop Mate](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86591/piece-drop-mate)

[Piece-drop Mate #2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86602/piece-drop-mate-2)

Here's a third one and an interesting one at that:

Your task is to place a piece on the board as White and checkmate Black.

The correct answer is the one which places the lowest-value piece possible on the board to checkmate Black.

Outside of this piece drop, **all rules of regular chess apply,** including piece limits (i.e. no more than 8 pawns can be on the board at 1 point.)

Good luck! ;)

[image]

Comment: #4 is out now - go check it out! https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86619/piece-drop-mate-4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think

> 3 points is minimum

Where

> a knight goes on f7.  One of the three knights is a promoted pawn

Comment: Whoa, I didn't expect you to solve it that fast!

Comment: I can't even mark it correct yet!

Comment: Now I'll have to make a 4th one already! :(

Answer (score 2):

Since the puzzle doesn't say that the checkmate must be immediate, allowing for a placement and then a move is made with mate, I believe that under these circumstances:

> 1 point is the minimum

Place:

> A pawn on g6, and move the White rook to h7 with checkmate to follow right away. The pawn can legally be there, as it has from 4 captures from it's home square on c2.

Comment: I said "put a white piece on the board and checkmate black." This implies that the placement checkmates Black.

Comment: Also, I said that all rules of chess apply, meaning that it would be Black to move after @g6, and Black could play Qxc1#

Comment: But nice idea :)

Comment: Fine, you got me. I'll try to be more explicit next time ;)