# Piece-drop Mate #4

Tags: chess

[Piece-Drop Mate](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86591/piece-drop-mate)

[Piece-drop Mate #2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86602/piece-drop-mate-2)

[Piece-drop Mate #3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86616/piece-drop-mate-3)

Here's another installation of the Piece-drop Mate series!

I'll try to be more explicit about the rules of the puzzle, as recommended by @Rewan Demontay.

This time, the position is one where Black wins. He makes a regular move and places a piece on the board at the **same time**, resulting in a position in which White is *checkmated*. White ***never*** gets the chance to make a move in this puzzle.

As usual, **everything about the position must be legal** (except for the fact that you are making a move and placing a piece at the same time, of course) (i.e. the position can't have more than 8 pawns at any given moment.)

Good luck!

[image]

### EDIT:

@Rewan Demontay was such a stickler about the legality of this that I have to include the fact that position can only arise from a Chess960 position due to the bishop on e8.

Comment: It's hard to require a legal position of the position that you have is illegal-The black bishop on e8 couldn't possibly get there, but I suppose that you could call it a Chess 960 game for some salvation.

Comment: I intended it to be reminiscent of Chess960

Comment: Even Chess960 doesn't save the impossible pawn structures from earlier puzzles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The move is d5. Knight on c8 is the placed piece, giving 3 points.

Comment: Oh, I didn't think of the moving part. Nice!

Comment: Correct! Well done!

Comment: Can anyone post an answer with all 3 moves?

Comment: Obviously, there are a variety of different answers here. One can place a knight on a8 or c8, or a bishop on c7 or a7.

Answer (score 0):

## 5 points:

> Rook at b4

## 6 points:

> Knights at d4 and b2

## 9 points:

> Queen at b4

Obviously this is not an optimal solution and shall be expanded upon later...

Comment: Yeah your rook answer might be the best placing-only solution.

Comment: @JoshuaBizley - Yeah, you could just move a random pawn to add a move to it, though...